# Monthly Time series data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot monthly time series with data below and I am getting the Error:

```
Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only*
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

below is my code:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())
rdata1_m <- rdata1[1:36, ]
lbls <-paste0(month.abb[month(rdata1_m$date)], " ",lubridate::year(rdata1_m$date))
brks <- rdata1_m$date 
ggplot(rdata1_m, aes(x=date)) +geom_line(aes(y=GoldPrice)) +
scale_x_date(labels = lbls,breaks = brks) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

and my data is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQNKm.png)

Comment: Please provide more information - share the code as well.

Comment: below is my code: theme_set(theme_bw())`rdata1_m <- rdata1[1:36, ]`lbls <-
paste0(month.abb[month(rdata1_m$date)], " ",lubridate::year(rdata1_m$date))brks <- rdata1_m$date ggplot(rdata1_m, aes(x=date)) +geom_line(aes(y=GoldPrice)) +scale_x_date(labels = lbls,breaks = brks) theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank()).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code

Comment: the data is date             GoldPrice
2004-11-01 439.38
2004-12-01 442.08
2005-01-01 424.03
2005-02-01 423.35
2005-03-01 433.85
2005-04-01 429.23
2005-05-01 421.87
2005-06-01 430.66
2005-07-01 424.48
2005-08-01 437.93
2005-09-01 456.05
2005-10-01 469.9
2005-11-01 476.67
2005-12-01 510.1
2006-01-01 549.86
2006-02-01 555
2006-03-01 557.09
2006-04-01 610.65
2006-05-01 675.39
2006-06-01 596.15
2006-07-01 633.71
2006-08-01 632.59
2006-09-01 598.19
2006-10-01 585.78
2006-11-01 627.83
2006-12-01 629.79

Comment: Comments are not to add crucial parts of the question. Please update your question adding the relevant data in there. Please try as much as possible to stick to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert to a zoo time series object with `yearmon` class index.  The `yearmon` class represents monthly data, i.e. dates containing a year and month but no day.  Finally use `autoplot.zoo` together with `scale_x_yearmon`.  See `?scale_x_yearmon` for arguments that can be used to customize it if you don't like the defaults.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(rdata, FUN = as.yearmon)
autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearmon(format = "'%y/%m")
```

Another possibility is to convert to a `ts` object and then use autoplot.ts from ggfortify.  Using `z` and the library statements from above we write

```
library(ggfortify)

autoplot(as.ts(z))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "date GoldPrice 
2004-11-01 439.38 
2004-12-01 442.08 
2005-01-01 424.03 
2005-02-01 423.35 
2005-03-01 433.85 
2005-04-01 429.23 
2005-05-01 421.87 
2005-06-01 430.66 
2005-07-01 424.48 
2005-08-01 437.93 
2005-09-01 456.05 
2005-10-01 469.9 
2005-11-01 476.67 
2005-12-01 510.1 
2006-01-01 549.86 
2006-02-01 555 
2006-03-01 557.09 
2006-04-01 610.65 
2006-05-01 675.39 
2006-06-01 596.15 
2006-07-01 633.71 
2006-08-01 632.59 
2006-09-01 598.19 
2006-10-01 585.78 
2006-11-01 627.83 
2006-12-01 629.79"

rdata <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the date column is not class date. Use `lubridate` to change the date and then plot. Also, you can set the breaks and labels much easier using `date_labels` and `date_breaks`.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)


rdata1 <- read_table2("date GoldPrice 
                                    2004-11-01 439.38 
                                    2004-12-01 442.08 
                                    2005-01-01 424.03 
                                    2005-02-01 423.35 
                                    2005-03-01 433.85 
                                    2005-04-01 429.23 
                                    2005-05-01 421.87 
                                    2005-06-01 430.66 
                                    2005-07-01 424.48 
                                    2005-08-01 437.93 
                                    2005-09-01 456.05 
                                    2005-10-01 469.9 
                                    2005-11-01 476.67 
                                    2005-12-01 510.1 
                                    2006-01-01 549.86 
                                    2006-02-01 555 
                                    2006-03-01 557.09 
                                    2006-04-01 610.65 
                                    2006-05-01 675.39 
                                    2006-06-01 596.15 
                                    2006-07-01 633.71 
                                    2006-08-01 632.59 
                                    2006-09-01 598.19 
                                    2006-10-01 585.78 
                                    2006-11-01 627.83 
                                    2006-12-01 629.79")

rdata1 %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, GoldPrice)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]